# ClojureScript Macro Gone Awry

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

**Goal:** I'm trying to make a macro which takes as an input something like the following:

```
(cb-chan (.readFile "/path/to/file" "utf8" _))
```

and returns as an output something like the following:

```
(go (let [c (chan 1)
          rep (.readFile "path/to/file" "utf8" (>? c)]  ; >? is a function that I defined elsewhere that jams the result of a callback into a channel
     rep
     (<! c))))
```

Notice that the `_` in the original input is being replaced by special callback (defined elsewhere). This callback jams its result into a channel, which is then retrieved and returned at end of the go block.

**Attempt:**

```
(defmacro cb-chan [func]
   `(cljs.core.async.macros/go 
      (let [~'c    (cljs.core.async/chan 1)]
           ~'rep  (replace (quote {~'_ (cljs-async-patterns.core/>? ~'c) }) (quote ~func))

       ~'rep
       (~'<! ~'c))))
```

**Result:** This fails since `rep` is just ends up being a literal, unevaluated list. If I were able to type `(eval rep)` on the second to last line instead of just `rep`, my problem would be fixed, but I cannot since I'm working in ClojureScript (where there is no eval). How do I get around this?

Comment: What you want here is quite unclear. Strings don't have a `.readFile` method, so `(.readFile "/path/to/file")` can never be correct. There's no reason at all to `(let [rep (foo)] rep x)`, instead of just writing `(do (foo) x)`. You probably just want to write `~(replace ...)` instead of `(replace ...)`, but it's hard to be sure since your desired input and outpot don't entirely make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, what do you need is probably a bit different. look at your desired code

```
(go (let [c (chan 1)
          rep (.readFile "path/to/file" "utf8" (>? c)]
      rep
      (<! c))))
```

do you really need to bind a var `rep`? what you want is probably this:

```
(go (let [c (chan 1)]
      (.readFile "path/to/file" "utf8" (>? c)
      (<! c))))
```

because there is no need for `rep`

however, you should consider rereading some articles about macros, because here you have a mess of random qoutes and unquotes.

the macro generating your code would look like this:

```
(defmacro cb-chan [func]
  (let [c (gensym "c")]
    `(cljs.core.async.macros/go 
       (let [~c (cljs.core.async/chan 1)
             rep# ~(replace {'_ `(cljs-async-patterns.core/>? ~c)} func)]
         rep#
         (cljs.core.async/<! ~c)))))
```

it will expand `(cb-chan (.readFile "/path/to/file" "utf8" _))` to this:

```
(cljs.core.async.macros/go
  (let [c19307 (cljs.core.async/chan 1)
        rep__19301__auto__ (.readFile
                             "/path/to/file"
                             "utf8"
                             (cljs-async-patterns.core/>? c19307))]
    rep__19301__auto__
    (cljs.core.async/<! c19307)))
```

for my variant (without `rep`):

```
(defmacro cb-chan [func]
  (let [c (gensym "c")]
    `(cljs.core.async.macros/go 
       (let [~c (cljs.core.async/chan 1)]
         ~(replace {'_ `(cljs-async-patterns.core/>? ~c)} func)
         (cljs.core.async/<! ~c)))))
```

expands to:

```
(cljs.core.async.macros/go
  (let [c19313 (cljs.core.async/chan 1)]
    (.readFile
      "/path/to/file"
      "utf8"
      (cljs-async-patterns.core/>? c19313))
    (cljs.core.async/<! c19313)))
```

Comment: My original question was not as well-formed as it could have been, but this answer was extraordinarily clarifying.